# pandas groupby function creates ascii encode error

Tags: python, pandas, ascii

when I try to do a groupby function in pandas i get ascii error. Not sure how to get around it.

sample_code:

```
name, group in df_ap.groupby(['My_column'])
```

error:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: check your data that your passing

Comment: I should convert the data to utef-8 before i process it. Thats the way to go about it.

Comment: You can add that answer to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way around this problem is to use the `encoding='utf-8` option in read_csv. This way the data is already in the right format.